# Button must be clicked twice to activate "contenteditable"

Tags: jquery, onclick, contenteditable

I'm dynamically setting the attribute of a button to `contenteditable=true` using a jQuery `click()` event.

```
$('.editable').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
    //$(this).focus(); -- setting this causes blur after typing one character
});
```

The problem is that the button must be clicked twice in order to trigger the editing. I have tried using `focus()`, but this causes the `blur()` event to trigger after typing just one character in the button. The same `click` handler works fine for editing other elements (ie; DIV).

<kbd>[**Bootply Example**](http://bootply.com/62420)</kbd> that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I click it once and the content becomes editable. FF, Chrome, IE9, Opera.

Comment: It becomes editable, but you have to click it again to begin editing. At least, that's what i'm seeing in Chrome.

Comment: Huh. Strange I've tried FF and Chrome (27.0.14) and no luck with the button -- must be clicked twice.

Comment: Skelly, see KevinB's comment

Comment: Skeely, sorry for my answer, i didn't have read the commented part

Comment: For me,  setting focus doesn't fired blur after typing one character, isn't it working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3L9XE/   (tested on chrome)

Comment: Yeah, that does work for me.. Why don't you post another answer?

Comment: @roasted: The reason it is working is because you removed the `on("blur"...` listener. If you add the listener, it behaves exactly as the Skelly's demo (and Skelly's demo works (just like yours) if you remove the `on("blur"...` part there as well).

Comment: @ExpertSystem in fact, i didn't have seen Skelly example, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a 100% solution, rather a workaround, but it might have the effect you want to achieve: You could wrap the text inside the `<button>` tag in a span and set its class to "editable".

```
<button id="editBtn" type="button">
    <span class="editable">Click to edit me</span>
</button>
```

Then you have to focus on click, e.g. like that:

```
$(".editable").on("click", function(evt) {
    $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true")
           .focus();
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/HdyEe/)**.